# Understanding PromQL in grafana.com dashboard

Tags: prometheus, grafana, promql

I am trying out django dashboards for grafana. I imported a [django/overview dashbord from grafana.com](https://grafana.com/grafana/dashboards/17617-django-overview/). One of its panel contained following PromQL:

```
sum (
  rate (
    django_cache_get_hits_total {
      namespace=~"$namespace",
      job=~"$job",
    }[30m]
  )
) by (namespace, job)
/
sum (
  rate (
    django_cache_get_total {
      namespace=~"$namespace",
      job=~"$job",
    }[30m]
  )
) by (namespace, job)
```

The panel was showing `NaN`:
[image]

I checked namespace drop down, it contained None entry and job drop down contained `django-prometheus` entry. I removed both from query and removed the denominator

```
sum (
  rate (
    django_cache_get_hits_total {
    }[30m]
  )
)
```

And it started to show 0%:
[image]

There are no entries for metric `django_cache_get_hits_total`:
[image]

**Q1.** Whats wrong here?

Also all panels had job and namespace. So, all panels were initially NaN. When I removed them, they started to show some good numbers. **Q2.** Is it fine to remove them?